# Opening a popup after receving message via postMessage

Tags: javascript, popup, cross-domain, postmessage

There is an iframe on my site which is hosted on another domain. It can communicate to the main site via window.postMessage. I do have a button on that iframe which calls a JS method on the main domain, which then triggers a new window.

It all seems good but since the user click event is generated on the iframe domain and window is created on the main domain, browser thinks that this is an automated popup, and blocks.

Is there anything I can do to prevent browser from blocking the window?

Answer (score 0):

since that is browser based you cannot overwrite browser settings. But you can use javascript "modals" which are very useful since they are not pop-ups but they don't have the functionality of an pop-up

Comment: I'm actually calling an API function which in turn opens up a new window, so unfortunately modal is not an option.

Comment: then sorry you cannot overwrite user settings on browser.